# Scale free property of Pareto distribution

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to show that the Pareto distribution is scale free, defined as:
`p(bx) = g(b)p(x)`
I get to this stage:
`x dp/dx = p'(1)/p(1) p(x)`
I have a rough solution which simply jumps to the next step:
`ln(p(x)) = p(1)/p'(1) ln(x) + ln(p(1))`
Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the given equation, we have:

$$x \frac{\mathrm dp}{\mathrm dx} = \frac{p'(1)}{p(1)}p(x) \iff \frac{p'(x)}{p(x)} = \frac{p'(1)}{p(1)}\cdot \frac1x$$

and by the chain rule $\dfrac{\mathrm d(\log p(x))}{\mathrm dx} = \dfrac{p'(x)}{p(x)}$.

Integrating both sides with respect to $x$ gives the desired expression

$$\log p(x) = \dfrac{p'(1)}{p(1)}\log x+\log p(1)$$

because at $x = 1$ both expressions agree (thus verifying the choice of the constant of integration).

Comment: Didn't realise it was so simple. Cheers!

Comment: Sometimes a fresh pair of eyes is all that is needed :).